# Where can I find data to apply data mining techniques?

Tags: associations, data-mining

Are there any websites that provides data (of any topic) to apply data mining techniques such as classification and association rules?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Interesting data Mining Websites](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4232380/interesting-data-mining-websites)

Comment: please, don't submit the same question again

Answer (score 1):

http://www.fedstats.gov/

Answer (score 0):

A great source is [UCI Machine Learning Repositor](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/)